# How long does Google chrome takes to reflect the statistics of extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I followed yesterday's statistics of my chrome extension in google chrome developer dashboard but there are not any data reflected yet. I'm sure about some installation and impressions. 
How long does it take to see the real results? 3 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically they lag behind only a day. But sometimes there are gaps and delays. Right now I'm not seeing any missing data.